# Stellar UTF-8 Support

Tags: stellar

We are developing the open government auctions system on “Stellar” platform.  We forked Stellar and run our own network. We’ve added Lot creation transactions, auction participation, bids etc. There is encoding problem. We tried this solution:  https://github.com/stellar/js-stellar-base/issues/60 But during the debug process we’ve find out that Stellar-core can’t process the data sent by js-xdr library in base64 (UTF-8) format. We’ve looked at the C++ source code but haven’t found the way to fix that.

Error example: 
{\"exception\"=>\"Non-zero padding bytes encountered\"}"

Some help and/or advice on this issue will be much appreciated.

All source are available here: http://www.eauction.idf.solutions/

Comment: When you say "on Stellar platform", do you mean the software or the network? That is, are you expecting to need no code changes or have your code changes accepted by the network? Are are you writing your own software (based on Stellar's software) to run your own network?

Comment: Yes, we forked Stellar and run our own network. All source are available here: http://www.eauction.idf.solutions .

Comment: Can you post the xdr blob that is causing the issue?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Our mistake. 
This commit solve the problem: https://github.com/stellar/js-xdr/pull/4/commits/119a8c26f71de8568d88cee1a94cb33074797859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in count of characters encoded in tx. C++ code allocate memory depending of count variable in tx. 
This commit solve the problem: https://github.com/stellar/js-xdr/pull/4/commits/119a8c26f71de8568d88cee1a94cb33074797859